# Windows 8 Restore Problems

Tags: windows, windows-8, hard-drive, backup

I created a Windows 8 system image backup on a separate drive before I installed Linux, and during the Linux installation process I accidentally wiped out Windows.  I now want to restore my Windows 8 backup that I have on the separate drive.  I created a repair USB stick and I followed the directions according to [this](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9064-system-image-recovery-restore-image-computer-windows-8-a.html) article.  After selecting the image on the hard drive, I get this error: "To restore this computer, Windows needs to format the hard drive."  I don't know what this means!  The drive partitions are different now then they were when I backup up, so I don't know if that matters.  I re-installed Windows and I can restore my files from this backup, but I don't think this covers the registry, etc.  I want a full restore.  Does anyone know how to fix this problem, or how to restore in a different way?  Thanks!

Comment: when you wiped out your "windows", you probably formated the hd/partition to ext3/ext4/whatever instead of leaving the partition as a ntfs file system.  **SYSTEM IMAGE** backup usually means a FULL Recovery is possible. How large is the image? If you dont care about the linux anymore, then wipe it and do it. You cant lose anything by doing it. You either have it or you don't.

Comment: I'm trying to do it, and that's when I get the error.  When it failed, I installed windows 8 on a clean drive.  Now I want my old stuff back

Comment: Windows8 your old stuff? or linux? I would try the install again but make sure the hd was clear of all partitions.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good thing you did a backup first. You need not worry what you want is the format first. Just choose the option to reformat and continue from there. If you want to try out Linux I suggest you do a little studying first about its basics so you don't run into this problem again. It is very confusing to a new user. I suggest trying out Ubuntu it is a popular distro for beginners. Installation information is [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation) Some useful info [here](http://manuals.bioinformatics.ucr.edu/home/linux-basics). Good luck. :)

Comment: The whole problem is that I can't make it to that step... I'm never able to get to the screen that allows me to reformat

Comment: If you use a live cd from ubuntu you can use gparted to create partitions. Just create a NTFS partition large enough for your recovery + extra for typical usage (downloads, etc.). Leave a partition available for linux at this point if you like. Then after you finish making your partitions reboot to your recovery USB and your error should be gone. Good luck

Comment: I've already erased Ubuntu, reformatted the drive, and re-installed windows

Comment: You can still use your backup now since you have Windows installed again. If you decide to try it again the links above are good places to start.